# Why pep8/flake8 cannot detect unbound local variable only declared in if branch

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

Given a simple code like below:

```
def func(flag):
    if flag:
        seq = range(3)
    return seq[1]
```

pep8 and flake8 both think this piece of code is good. Why could this happen? `seq` is only defined under `if` clause.

Comment: pep8 and flake8 aren't really code analyzers, they're more like style checkers.

Comment: `seq` could have been defined outside the function.

Comment: @Fabian: No it couldn't - `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'seq' referenced before assignment`

Comment: This utility (pep8) does not enforce every single rule of PEP 8. It helps to verify that some coding conventions are applied but it does not intend to be exhaustive. Some rules cannot be expressed with a simple algorithm, and other rules are only guidelines which you could circumvent when you need to.

Comment: @Eric only if the pasted code is the entire file.

Comment: @Marius, still in the [documentation](http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) there are examples of code analysis (`F841 local variable 'errors' is assigned to but never used`). I installed `pylint`, but even it didn't detect the possible bug.

Comment: You'll need a more complex analyzer for this. PyCharm detects this possible error.

Comment: @Fabian: [Are you sure?](http://ideone.com/nUbs9y)

Comment: @Eric yes: https://gist.github.com/vortec/7080893

Comment: @Fabian: Now try that with an unreachable assignment to `foo` in the function, which is what causes `foo` to become a local variable

Comment: @Eric dang! You are right, thanks for pointing this out! Should I delete my comments because of possible mis-information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any specific knowledge about the design and implementation of `pep8`, but detecting conditionally-undefined variables *in general* is a tricky business. For example, consider the following code:

```
def func(value):
    if value < 2:
        raise ValueError()
    for p in generate_primes():
        if value % p == 0:
            smallest_prime_factor = p
            break
    do_something_with(smallest_prime_factor)
```

Now, the programmer knows that as long as you pass in an integer, one of the tests will pass. The static analysis tool doesn't know that. So what is your tool going to do?

- require an `else` clause on the loop (in which case you won't get full code coverage for your tests unless you inject a mock version of `generate_primes` that doesn't satisfy the contract of `generate_primes`)
- require initialization with something like `smallest_prime_factor = 1` before the loop (which misleadingly implies to a reader of the code that there's a case to deal with where the result *isn't* initialized in the loop).
- disable the check just for this variable (https://github.com/cburroughs/pep8.py/issues/12)
- don't diagnose conditionally-undefined variables (which means you'll miss some errors).

It looks to me as though `pep8` has gone for the simple and conservative option: it doesn't diagnose something that might not be incorrect. The fix is not to rely solely on static analysis tools, and *certainly* not to rely solely on tools that are designed primarily to detect issues of style rather than of code correctness. Write tests with full code coverage -- then for your code the test where `flag` is false will throw, diagnosing your error.